# 3ware 9690-SA and 3TB drives

Tags: raid, hardware-raid, 3ware

Does the 3ware 9690-SA support 3TB drives?  Can I create a logical volume of 8x3TB drives in RAID5?

Answer (score 1):

See this knowledgebase article:
http://kb.lsi.com/KnowledgebaseArticle16481.aspx
It will work, you just need to update your firmware a bit.

Answer (score 0):

The [3ware drive compatibility list](http://www.3ware.com/products/pdf/Drive_compatibility_list_9690SA_9.5.3codeset_900-0070-02RevL.pdf) does not contain any drives over 2TB in size.  That is not to say they won't work - just that 3ware haven't tested them yet.

Comment: Thanks -- Do you happen to know if 3TB drives in general can be recognized by the 9690-SA?